# Windows Phone 7 HTTP Upload, no AllowWriteStreamBuffering property available

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0, httpwebrequest, windows-phone-7

I'm creating an HttpWebRequest and storing it inside of an HttpState object. When I go to set AllowWriteStreamBuffering property of the request to false, I see that no such property exists. The download counterpart, AllowReadStreamBuffering, is available.

```
HttpState httpState = new HttpState();
httpState.request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(this.remotepath);
//this compiles
httpState.request.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;
//this doesn't compile
httpState.request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is there really no way to specify the buffering property for the WriteStream in Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 3):

It appears as though MS has removed a lot of stream API support for Windows Phone 7.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470087%28VS.96%29.aspx

AllowWriteStreamBuffering is not listed on the aforementioned document as unsupported, but it is not recognized by the compiler as a valid property. Ostensibly, also affected is the SendChunked property.
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/169859/382978.aspx

How frustrating.

Comment: Well you understand how WP7 is still in its infancy.